# How to reduce size of firebase.js in my rails app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `firebase.js` and `firebase-messaging.js` in my rails for notifications.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

It works fine but issue is that 117.5KB and my application JS size is 87.5KB.

How can I reduce the size of firebase.js.

Comment: It will probably get smaller in prod when files are minimized. Otherwise only option to reduce is to remove code, but that works only if firebase is modular. You should check their docs to see if you can install only what you need. But 110kb isn't that bad considering the current speed of internet right?

Comment: its size after minimized on production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the full Firebase SDK `firebase.js` and then re-loading the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK (`firebase-messaging.js`) on top of that.

To reduce the size, only load the parts you need. In this case that seems:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Version 4.10.1 of `firebase-app.js` is only 11.4K compared to the 117K of `firebase.js`.

Comment: and it do same functionality?

Comment: `firebase.js` contains the SDKs for all Firebase products, so it cover a lot more. But if you're only using FCM, these two are the only ones needed.

Comment: can you give me firebase-app.js link because I can't find it

Comment: It's right there in my answer: `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.1/firebase-app.js`.